# Why background color stay white? (Xamarin.Forms Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an xamarin.forms application and try to publish it in android.
In my simulator, the color of the background is gray.
On android mobile the background stays white like default.
What do i wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns=http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms
             xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#202020">
    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource mainBg}">
        <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#202020">
            <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource mainBg}">
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Style="{StaticResource mainBgBorder}">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Image x:Name="imMyPicLogo" Source="MyPic.png" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
          </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: And mainBg is only BackgroundColor=”#202020” as value

Answer (score 0):

go to app.xaml or appshell.xaml and change a background color.

Answer (score 0):

Works here .

In `App.xaml` mainBg and mainBgBorder. The Android phone is in Lightmode.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout" x:Key="mainBg">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#202020" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Frame" x:Key="mainBgBorder" >
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then the `ContentPage`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BackgroundSO.MainPage"
         BackgroundColor="#202020">
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource mainBg}">
    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#202020">
        <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource mainBg}">
            <Frame HasShadow="True" Style="{StaticResource mainBgBorder}">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Image x:Name="imMyPicLogo" Source="schip.png" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it. The problem should be due to the style attribute setting of stacklayout. You can try changing it like this：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns=http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms
         xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
         BackgroundColor="#202020">
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#202020">
        <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource mainBg}">
            <Frame HasShadow="True" Style="{StaticResource mainBgBorder}">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Image x:Name="imMyPicLogo" Source="MyPic.png" 
HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

By the way, if you can, you may provide more information about the mainBgBorder.

Comment: <Style x:Key="mainBg" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#202020" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="mainBgBorder" TargetType="Frame">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />
            </Style>

Comment: Well, then my answer should be no problem.